# How to count how many candles between current time and opening candle in the previous week

Tags: pine-script

How can I know how many 1H candles are between current time and and the first trading day in the previous week.

For example today is Tuesday 10:40 Am and the first trading day in the previous week was Monday so I should get 44 candles, previous week was 5 trading days and each day have 7 1H candles so that's 35 and Monday current week is 7 and the 9:30 am and 10:30 am candle on Tuesday so that's 44.

How do I automate this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the function I got from a guy in Reddit

```
numBars = 35

t = time('W')

if t == t[1]
    numBars := nz(numBars[1]) + 1
else
    numBars := 35
```

Comment: Ok. Just keep in mind that if you encounter a trading session with a shortened time or need to switch to a different timeframe, this script will not work. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Set the date and time from which to start counting candlesticks, works for all timeframes.

```
//@version=4
study("Help (bar counter)", overlay=false)

Year   = input(2021, "Year")
Month  = input(02,   "Month")
Day    = input(12,   "Day")
Hour   = input(10,   "Hour")
Minute = input(1,    "Minute")

var Counter = 1

if timestamp(Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, 00) < time
    Counter := Counter + 1

plot(Counter)
```

Comment: Do you still need help?